# Widget display nothing

Tags: widgets

I have 6 widgets in Wordpress. Three works correct, but three display nothing. Code of one which is not working is:

```
register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => __('Title Footer Menu Third'),
        'id'   => 'sidebar-title-c',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  => '',
        'after_title'   => ''
    ));
```

I try to display this into footer.php just like that:

```
<p style="font-size: 12px;margin-top:-4px;font-weight: 900;color: #fff;border-bottom: solid 1px #02B4EA;padding-bottom: 5px;"><?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("sidebar-title-c") ) :  ?>
<?php endif;?></p>
```

Why is not working for all six widgets?

Comment: do you see all six corresponding widget areas in the dashboard under 'Appearance' - 'Widgets'? and did you add at least one widget into each of the areas?

Comment: When you say widget, do you mean a widget in a sidebar, or do you mean a sidebar itself? It looks like you've muddled up sidebars and widgets, or at least I think you have, it makes the question confusing

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is empty. Also I don't think your `if` statement is correct.
Can you try this:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-title-c' ) ) : ?>
    <p style="font-size: 12px;margin-top:-4px;font-weight: 900;color: #fff;border-bottom: solid 1px #02B4EA;padding-bottom: 5px;">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-title-c' ); ?>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```